SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module ts-jest
I'm using TypeScript, ESM, npm, and ts-jest. Unfortunately, it seems that transformIgnorePatterns isn't working.
I've tried multiple configurations, but nothing has helped me run Jest with ts-jest successfully. The only workaround that worked was replacing imports with require directly in node_modules, but that's not a viable final solution.
the error is:

My package.json has "type": "module". I'm using npm workspaces, my setup in the root is very similar to the one in my child package:
jest.config.ts
export default {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testMatch: ['**/*.spec.ts'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': ['ts-jest']
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!log-symbols|picocolors)']
};

ts.config.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2022",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "declaration": true,
        "strict": true,
        "incremental": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "composite": true,
        "types": ["node", "jest"],
        "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "noEmit": true,
    },
    "ts-node": {
        "esm": true
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

I've tried various configurations with transformIgnorePatterns, target, and module values. The issue occurs not only with picocolors but also with chalk (versions 5 and 4).

I didn't come up with a valid solution. In the end, I decided to stop using log-symbols, and I chose picocolors instead of chalk.
For piccolors It works without transformIgnorePatterns

